# `swift build` on Terminal throw `error: root manifest not found`

Tags: swift, build, terminal

I wanna run my swift programing on Terminal, so I `cd` the root folder of my project, and run `$ swift build`, but there is a error occurred. 
`$ error: root manifest not found`
Any help?

Comment: Hope [this](https://github.com/exercism/swift/issues/274) can help you

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone else stumble upon the same problem, the solution for me was to cd to the Sources folder of my scripts, not the root folder.

Comment: This probably means you have your package setup incorrectly— you probably have your `Package.swift` file inside your `Sources/` directory.  It should instead be in the root level of your package, as a sibling to the `Sources/` directory.  Long story short, whatever directory your `Package.swift` is in is considered the root of the package, so by putting it in the `Sources/` dir, you've essentially (sort of, also not correct) created a package named “Sources”.

Comment: I don't think it was the case, as I never committed the package anywhere but at the root of the package, along with the generated xcodeproj and the Sources folder. That being said, I can't be 100% sure of it, as I was in the process of creating the first commit of the package when I gave my answer. Whatever the case, I guess your reply could help anyone that has such a folder structure, though :).

Answer (score 4):

I had this error happen to me when I was building a **CLI tool** on Xcode.  First off, when Xcode talks about `root manifest`, it means `package.swift`. You don't have one in your directory or parent directories. I discovered 2 options:

##### Instead of `swift build`, use Xcode's UI or `xcodebuild` CLI and get the build files in finder/ terminal

- For debug, build the build normally, and you can right click the file generated in the `Project Navigator` like below:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

- For release build, run `Archive` in Xcode instead and you can get the build files: `Project Name 25-03-2021, 11.30.xcarchive/Products/usr/local/bin/executable` in my case the executable is called `Image Labeling`

##### or, add a package.swift

Instead of creating the project through Xcode (CLI tool template) use the `swift` cli tool instead: `swift package init --type executable` . In this case, `swift build` works everywhere in the project, not just in `Sources` because `package.swift` was added to the root of the project.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the

```
-Swift build
```

command you must use it from **Swift Package Manager** and you should have 2 folders in the directory:

```
Source
Test
```

you should use the following command for project:

```
 - name: Build
      run: |
          xcodebuild clean test -project "yourproject.xcproject" -scheme "yourproject" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro,OS=latest" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

and you should use the following commands for workspace:

```
- name: Build
     run: |
           xcodebuild clean build -workspace "yourproject.xcworkspace" -scheme "yourtarget" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro,OS=latest" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
     
- name: Test
     run: |
           xcodebuild clean test -workspace "yourproject.xcworkspace" -scheme "yourtargetTests" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro,OS=latest" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```