# How to unit test iOS package with `swift test`?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have an iOS library with Swift package manager. I am trying to run unit tests with  `swift test`
The reason why I am not using `xcodebuild` is, I am trying to remove the `.xcodeproj` from my source control. Also, there is a warning when we create `xcodeproj` with spm, that generate-xcodeproj will be deprecated soon.
TL;DR
This library depends on Lottie
I tried just running `swift test`  in the root directory, but it gives lot of errors. like /.build/checkouts/lottie-ios/lottie-swift/src/Public/Animation/AnimationView.swift:859:11: error: cannot find 'superview' in scope
I tried

```
swift test -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios14.5-simulator"
```

Then it gives the error `error: module 'XCTest' was created for incompatible target x86_64-apple-macos10.15`. I did not specify macos10.15 anywhere, I am on macOS 11.5.1

I can build the package using the above command by replacing `test` with `build`. What is wrong with my test command?

As I understand this is because I am not specifying the target simulator, is it possible to specify the target simulator with `swift test`?

Comment: Probably duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765408


https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13773

Comment: check my answer in this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754432/swift-build-on-terminal-throw-error-root-manifest-not-found/68863916#68863916
maybe helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`swift test` only works for macOS testing. It does not support cross builds for iOS.

You do not need an existing Xcode project to use `xcodebuild`.  Run the command, `xcodebuild -list` to initialize a `Package.swift` file for testing.

See the example [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/.github/workflows/spm.yml#L31).